# Use Environment Variables to PostgreSQL Config File postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, docker, variables, config

I have a custom DockerFile that build PostgreSQL with multiple extensions which are required from our software. Below is a sample of this DockerFile:

```
FROM postgres:15.4

# Update System
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /

#system preloaded libraries
RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries='pglogical,pg_cron'" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
#cron default database
RUN echo "cron.database_name=postgres" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

The above "RUN" commands are patching the postgresql.conf.sample file by adding some additional parameters (like cron.database_name=postgres) which are used by pg_cron extension to operate.

What if i want to make these parameters look into variable so then be able to change it from docker-compose or from kubernetes ConfigMap?

For example I tried this configuration:

```
FROM postgres:15.4

# Update System
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /

#system preloaded libraries
RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries='pglogical,pg_cron'" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
#cron default database
RUN echo "cron.database_name=$CRON_DATABASE_NAME" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

The above code produces this line in the end of the postgresql.conf file

```
cron.database_name=$CRON_DATABASE_NAME
```

instead of this line

```
cron.database_name=postgres
```

But postgres fails to start because seems it cannot understand $CRON_DATABASE_NAME as variable

On the other side seems that by setting the WAL_LEVEL environment variable works without being at all into postgresql.conf which is not the case for this additional parameter cron.database_name

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you could show us how you are setting this environment variable when you build your image?

Comment: The point is not to set the variables on build, but then be able to change them even from docker engine, either from kubernetes ConfigMap, so you could specify the variables with -e at docker run

Comment: RUN is only happening at build-time though, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, docker built is different than docker run, right? with docker build you build the image and with docker run you reference the image (adding variables if necessary) to start the container. So practically you can start multiple times same image with different params, right?

Comment: Yeah, but you are using RUN to echo the `cron.database_name` into the postgresql config file at build-time.

Comment: So? the RUN command into Docker file isn't different from docker run shell coommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that only some variables can be used as environment variables and those are the "postmaster" variables. These variables are flagged with "postmaster" flag into postgresql documentation.

```
environment:
   -pgdata=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
   -wal_level=logical
```

On the other side to set variables on postgresql startup (postmaster or not) like tuning parameters we can use the following code like arguments into docker compose or kubernetes stateful-set.

```
args:
   -c cron.database_name=postgres
   -c min_wal_size=1GB
   -c max_wal_size=4GB
```

The only issue is that we need to restart postgres to take effect.